# Cannot resolve symbol mapReduceTriplets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am using Spark 2.2, Scala 2.11 and GraphX. When I try to compile the folloiwing code in Intellij, I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol mapReduceTriplets`:

```
val nodeWeightMapFunc = (e:EdgeTriplet[VD,Long]) => Iterator((e.srcId,e.attr), (e.dstId,e.attr))
val nodeWeightReduceFunc = (e1:Long,e2:Long) => e1+e2
val nodeWeights = graph.mapReduceTriplets(nodeWeightMapFunc,nodeWeightReduceFunc)
```

I was reading [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/graphx-programming-guide.html) that it's possible to substitute `mapReduceTriplets` with `aggregateMessages`, but it's unclear how exactly can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapReduceTriplets` belonged to legacy API and has been removed from the public API. Specifically if you check [the current documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/graphx-programming-guide.html#map-reduce-triplets-transition-guide-legacy):

> In earlier versions of GraphX neighborhood aggregation was accomplished using the mapReduceTriplets operator